# How can the androids have important jobs, Garland, Luft?

Tags: do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

I don't remember how long Phillip K. Dick wrote the Nexus-6 androids had been on Earth but I recall they had only recently arrived. That being the case, how can they have important jobs like *Inspector* Garland (that everyone at his fake office knew, including a human bounty hunter) or be a *celebrated singer* like Luba Luft (I think Dick stated she was already famous)?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to the Nexus-6 models, or androids in general?

Comment: the recently scaped Nexus 6, yes.

Comment: In which case, I think Valorum's answer may suffice for you.

Answer (score 5):

### Luba Luft

Luba, is a Nexus 6 and has only recently arrived. Because of her advanced physiology and intellect, she's managed to get ahead *surprisingly quickly* through a combination of forged references and natural (ahem) talent.

> “An opera singer. Allegedly from Germany. At present attached to the
>   San Francisco Opera Company.” He nodded in reflexive agreement, his
>   mind on the poop sheet. **“Must have a good voice to make connections so
>   fast.** Okay, I’ll wait here for Kadalyi.” He gave Bryant his location
>   and rang off.

### Garland

Garland appears to have replaced a real Garland who was (ironically) an earlier model of android. It's possible that his make/model was physically similar.

> “According to it,” Rick said, “the bunch of them came to Earth together. And that wasn’t as long ago as three years; it’s only been a matter of months.”
>   **“Then at one time an authentic Garland existed,” Phil Resch said. “And somewhere along the way got replaced.”** His sharklike lean face twisted and he struggled to understand. “Or—I’ve been impregnated with a false memory system. Maybe I only remember Garland over the whole time. But—” His face, suffused now with growing torment, continued to twist and work spasmodically. **“Only androids show up with false memory systems; it’s been found ineffective in humans.”**